# How to pass -g3 flag to GCC via Make command line?

Tags: gcc, command-line, makefile

My project compiled with `-g` option instead of `-g3`, which means that I can't expand macros in gdb. I want to add the `-g3` flag to GCC, but I don't want to modify the makefile, I just want to add this flag via the Make command line.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

That depends on what the Makefile does/how it was written. It might not be possible.

If your Makefile is reasonably "standard", then this should work:

```
make CFLAGS="-g3 ..."
```

If it's for C++:

```
make CXXFLAGS="-g3 ..."
```

Comment: I understand your point, thank you!

Comment: yet another question, the variable CFLAGS may be already defined in my makefile, I just want to append the -g3 to it, not to assign it a new value, how can I do? Does it have a grammar like "CFLAGS+="-g3"" or something else?

Comment: @wangshuaijie I this that make CFLAGS:=$(CFLAGS) -g3 would append them

Comment: composes conveniently with `-Dblabla`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13127824/1959808

Comment: what is the meaning of "reasonably standard" ? Does that mean that the symbol CFLAGS must be defined in the Makefile and in that case using the command line parameter will prepend `-g3` to it?

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, regular warning flags can go inside of the 'CFLAGS' call too? I'm trying to use WError in this example and it's not working -- my command line looks like this:

` make CFLAGS="-O0 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror" -C <.... rest of it here....>`

Comment: @RaleighL. that syntax did work for me (for a different warning flag).