# Including a #define in all .c source files at compile time

Tags: c, gcc

I need to include a `#define` at the top of around 300 .c files.  I would prefer not to change the code as it is open source code but if I have to I will just write a script to modify all the files.  Is there a way using gcc to add a `#define` or header file include to the top of every source file during compilation?  The `#define` is this:

```
#define malloc MYmalloc
```

Comment: I suppose most of these .c files directly or indirectly `#include <stdlib.h>`.  Hmmm...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can pass `-Dmalloc=MYmalloc` to the `gcc` options.

For more information about the `-D` option:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Note that if you want to modify the behavior of `malloc` function for debugging purposes, you may also be interested in `glibc` `malloc` hooks:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

Comment: Thanks ouah, I'll try this out and I think it will solve my problems.  I know about the malloc hooks and LD_PRELOAD solutions but they aren't suitable to my situation.  Either way its good to mention it for other viewers.

Answer (score 7):

gcc option `-D`:

```
-D name
    Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1.

-D name=definition
    ....
```

so, in your case, `gcc ... -Dmalloc=MYmalloc`

Answer (score 0):

If you strive for redirecting `malloc()` calls to a custom function I would rather recommend to provide your custom code via pre-loading of your implementation at runtime. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262439/create-a-wrapper-function-for-malloc-and-free-in-c) question for details.